# How to remove /RTC1 from specific target or file in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

So I have a giant project that I joined with a bunch of cmake. Our debug builds run very slow, and we traced it back to both a specific target we are building (allegro legacy), and a specific file (ffscript.cpp). If we enable `/O2` for both of these, we can go from an unbearable 30 fps to 300 fps uncapped. The problem is that these are incompatible with [`/RTC1` (run-time error checks)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/rtc-run-time-error-checks), a flag which is apparently on (though I can't find where it's being set, so I assume CMake itself is setting it).

We figured out how to disable RTC1 for the entire project with `STRING (REGEX REPLACE "/RTC(su|[1su])" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}") STRING (REGEX REPLACE "/RTC(su|[1su])" "" CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG}")`, but realized that `/RTC1` sounds pretty useful everywhere else. We want to only disable it for this specific target and file but keep it elsewhere, but I cannot figure out the sanest way to do this that still works. I also want to add the `/O2` flags to the specific file; it's already added for the target, but I don't know how to add it to a specific file (though I know how to do it manually via VS2022, I'd prefer to not lose these changes each time the CMake gets updated). I don't know what I should share, but here's the CMake file for this specific target (there's multiple CMakeLists.txt files in this project): https://pastebin.com/gYUJUGpE

Could someone help me out? I don't really know how to CMake at all, and it's pretty daunting. Would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me and explain in a way I could understand. Thanks!

Note: There was one solution I found on Stack Overflow which involved taking the entire global with a macro and applying it to each target individually, but that caused compile errors and I had to revert it.

Comment: You're close to a good question, I think. Please read about [why 'Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541) and [edit] to pose a clear question. :)

Comment: I would also [edit] to add an actual link to that other Q&A you are referring to and maybe even describe what compiler errors you got when trying to use it. Just saying there is something you tried without saying what it was is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am not sure whether it is actually valid/safe to link between targets with different values of `/RTC`. Don't take this answer as any confirmation that what you want will work out.

As for where the `/RTC` flag is getting set, your hunch is right. It *can* be set by CMake. See [:/Modules/Platform/Windows-MSVC.cmake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Modules/Platform/Windows-MSVC.cmake) and search for "RTC". In particular, see the part which modifies `CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT`.

Achieving what you want (removing `/RTC` for a specific target) is a bit difficult because unlike GNU compilers, which allow disabling most previously-specified flags with a "`no-`" prefix, I'm not aware of the CL compiler offering similar functionality, combined with the fact that options in [`CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_CONFIG.html) exist separately from those in [the `COMPILE_OPTIONS` directory property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html) and [target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html), and is combined into the final list of compile options for a target/source-file near the end of the process of building that compile options list (as opposed to being used to initialize the directory and target properties).

One workaround could be to keep doing what you did (remove `/RTC` from `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` and `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG`), and then just add `/RTC` to the `COMPILE_OPTIONS` directory property of the root CMakeLists.txt via [`add_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html), which initializes the target property for all targets created/defined in subdirectories, and then remove `/RTC` from the target's `COMPILE_OPTIONS` property via [get_property(TARGET)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_property.html) and [`set_property(TARGET)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html).